# VS2010 C++ Concurrency Runtime - How to force single threaded mode?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, visual-studio-debugging

In VS2010, is there a way to force a Concurrency::parallel_for() loop (or parallel_for_each) to run in serial?  It would be easier for debugging.

If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could just replace it with `std::for_each`.

Comment: Also, you may go another route and try to learn to debug with many threads. MSDN has a walk-through [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx).

Comment: Would've been nice to have a flag that could be set at runtime to help rule out concurrency as a source of problems that customers experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a debug friendly build by using a define based on the `_DEBUG` preprocessor symbol to map the required functions to either serial (mostly found in std) or parallel versions. Of course this means a lot of effort, your way better off learn the useful skill of MT debugging as GMan suggested

Comment: yeah, I don't want to litter my code with lots of _DEBUG #ifdefs.  I guess I will work on learning the debugging tools ;(